# I am creating a book selling website using woo-commerce. where I want to use the book writer's name. how can I do that?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

I am creating a book selling website using woo-commerce. where I want to use the book writer's name.  how can I do that ? also book writer will have some basic information. its behavior like category

I will add a product ( book ) and there will be an option to assign one or more book writers.Book writer will have a profile simple page as like category page.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest creating a custom post type with the name 'Book Writer' will be a good solution.

First, create a custom post type with the name "book-writers". And then save all the book writers as a post.

Then create a custom meta-box in woo-commerce and name it "Assign a book author". And create a dynamic meta field as the select list in it, which will display a list of all posts of "book-writers" which are the name of the book writers. And save then save that meta field.

Before publishing the product select the book writer name you want to assign to that product and then publish the product.

This way you can add authors and their relevant data of the individual author. Without adding them as a user. And you can also create a detail description page for each book writer.

I hope you understand.

Add the below code in your function.php

```
function book_writer_meta_box(){
    add_meta_box(
        'book_writer_box_id',  // Unique ID
        'Assign a book author',  // Box title
        'render_book_writer_meta_box_html',
        'product',  // Post type
        'normal',
        'low'
    );
}
add_action('add_meta_boxes', 'book_writer_meta_box');


function render_book_writer_meta_box_html($post){
    $meta = get_post_meta( $post->ID );
    wp_nonce_field( 'book_writer_metabox', 'book_writer_metabox_nonce' );

    $val_bookWriter = ( isset( $meta['book_writer'][0] ) && '' !== $meta['book_writer'][0] ) ? $meta['book_writer'][0] : '';

    // print_r("<p>val_autoplayTime-".$val_autoplayTime."<p/>");
    echo "<div class='bookWriter_meta_fields_container'>";

    echo '<p><label for="book_writer"><b>Book Writer Name: </b></label><input type="text" name="book_writer" id="book_writer" style="width:100%;" value="'. esc_attr( $val_bookWriter ) .'"></p>';

    echo "</div>";
}


function book_writer_save_metadata($post_id){
    // Check if our nonce is set.
    if ( ! isset( $_POST['book_writer_metabox_nonce'] ) || ! wp_verify_nonce( sanitize_key( $_POST['book_writer_metabox_nonce'] ), 'book_writer_metabox' ) ) { // Input var okay.
            return $post_id;
    }

    // If this is an autosave, our form has not been submitted, so we don't want to do anything.
    if ( defined( 'DOING_AUTOSAVE' ) && DOING_AUTOSAVE ) {
        return $post_id;
    }

    // Check the user's permissions.
    if ( isset( $_POST['post_type'] ) && 'page' == $_POST['post_type'] ) {
        if ( ! current_user_can( 'edit_page', $post_id ) ) {
            return $post_id;
        }
    }
    else {
        if ( ! current_user_can( 'edit_post', $post_id ) ) {
            return $post_id;
        }
    }

     // OK, it's safe for us to save the data now. 

    // Make sure that it is set.
    if ( !isset($_POST['book_writer']) ) {
        return;
    }

    $fields = ['book_writer'];

    foreach ($fields as $field) {
        if (array_key_exists($field, $_POST)){
            update_post_meta($post_id, $field, sanitize_text_field($_POST[$field]));
        }
    }
}
add_action('save_post', 'book_writer_save_metadata');
```

Comment: Thank you for your Answer can you show me any example for "custom meta-box in woo-commerce and name it Assign a book author"

Comment: This is a basic example of creating a meta-box in any wordpress post type.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot add author as product category. it's better to use plugin for  selling books like https://www.wpini.com/woocommerce-bookstore-plugin/ if not you may make the author as product attribute (but it's not recommended)

Answer (score 0):

As per your requirement, I suggest creating a User Role named 'Book Writer'.
So based on this role, you can create as many as users(book writer) from User Menu having 'Book Writer' Role.

Now using the ACF field, you can list all the 'Book Writer' User in a product editor page of WooCommerce. You can give multiple selection options from the ACF too.

Once this is done, you will get the ids of the 'Book Writer' associated with the product('Book') and then you can link 'Book Writer' data to author.php file and you can customize that file as per your requirement to make the profile more attractive.

Hope this makes sense.

THanks

Comment: I am accepting the same process but without using wp_users  table Becaused Book Writer will never log in with this system

Comment: ok. You can achieve using CPT rather then Taxonomy. In CPT you will have single page that can be treated as profile page. Same process will be applied for CPT too.

Comment: It will possible relation with PRODUCT?